# Git packfile errors

Tags: git

I've a machine that dual boots between Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04.

On the shared file system there's a Git repository/workspace. It was created using msysgit from Windows.

When I try to use this repo under Linux (using Git 1.7.9.5), I see these error messages:

> error: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-31c385e8e4f1c105da16758ee98043a4b4ea1e50.pack signature is unavailable
>
> warning: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-31c385e8e4f1c105da16758ee98043a4b4ea1e50.pack cannot be accessed
>
> error: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-31c385e8e4f1c105da16758ee98043a4b4ea1e50.pack signature is unavailable
>
> warning: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-31c385e8e4f1c105da16758ee98043a4b4ea1e50.pack cannot be accessed
>
> fatal: failed to read object 190cb002f6257e33efe88a91b37943be29cf9412: Value too large for defined data type

Firstly, what do these mean?

Secondly, is this an indication that the contents of a `.git` folder are distribution dependent, whether by the OS or version/implementation of git?

I can work around this by making another clone of the repo, but I'd prefer to use the same one from both OS's if possible.

Comment: Could it be that you have Fast Boot active? If so, DISABLE IT! See this [article](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Linux-and-Windows-8-Fast-Startup-puts-data-at-risk-1780640.html)

Comment: Interesting. I'll boot back into Windows a little later to check whether the repo is corrupt from msysgit's perspective as well.

Comment: The repo works fine after rebooting into Windows.

Comment: I feel a [tumbleweed](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed) coming on...

Comment: Is the repo on a shared filesystem?  If so, what's the filesystem, NTFS?

Comment: @Charles, no it's not a shared filesystem -- it's an internal SSD. Yes it's NTFS.

Comment: @DrewNoakes, then I'm assuming you're using ntfs-3g under Linux?  Could it be an [ACL issue](http://b.andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/permissions.html)?

Comment: No, the contents of .git are not distribution dependent and should be extremely stable. This is most likely not a git issue, but a filesystem issue etc. You might want to retag your question ;).

Comment: @Chronial, could you suggest how I might explore this? Other repos created under Win work from Linux. This is the only one that shows this problem. Running `sudo git status` gives the same errors.

Comment: Aha! Running `gksu git status` works. I'd be interested to hear what this means and how I go about exploring this further as I'm at the edge of my knowledge here. I can't see anything from `ls -la` through the `.git/objects/pack/*` directories. Everything is owned by `root` and in the `root` group with 777 permissions.